# Android - get item id of a MenuItem clicked in a Submenu

Tags: android, navigation

I'm populating a submenu with an `ArrayList` of cities. I can't seem to figure out how to get the id of `MenuItem` clicked in the submenu. I couldn't find a method that might suit my needs.

Let me share my code with you. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitleTextAppearance(this, R.style.TextAppearance_Widget_Event_Toolbar_Title);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    mDrawerMenu = navigationView.getMenu();

    addCitiestoMenu();

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

**The method that add cities to the submenu**

```
private void addCitiestoMenu() {

    cityArrayList = RealmHelper.getStoredCities();
    SubMenu submenu = mDrawerMenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu();
    submenu.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_place_black_24dp);
    submenu.setHeaderTitle("test");

    int i = 0;

    for (City city: cityArrayList) {
        submenu.add(city.getCityName());
        submenu.getItem(i).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_place_black_24dp);
        i++;
    }
}
```

**The onNavigationItemSelected method in which I get the id of the clicked submenu**

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "id: "+id);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set an id on the menu items. Setting an id is only possible with one of the `add` methods of `Menu`, e.g. with [`Menu.add()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)). Change your `addCitiestoMenu()`:

```
private void addCitiestoMenu() {

    cityArrayList = RealmHelper.getStoredCities();
    SubMenu submenu = mDrawerMenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu();
    submenu.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_place_black_24dp);
    submenu.setHeaderTitle("test");

    for (City city : cityArrayList) {
        int cityId = city.getId(); // Get the id (You'll probably need to replace getId() )
        MenuItem item = submenu.add(Menu.NONE, cityId, Menu.NONE, city.getCityName());
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_place_black_24dp);
    }
}
```